# How to handle IBM Cloud Foundry Gorouter and its hard limit of 120 seconds response time?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have deployed an application on IBM Cloud Foundry, which has a REST API allowing other applications to send PDF files as input, returning a result object as response.

This application processes these PDF files doing various things (OCR, Natural Language Processing, detecting entities in the text, etc.). Unfortunately this kind of file processing can take its time.

Recently I was told that Cloud Foundry uses Gorouter for load balancing. Apparently Gorouter has a hard limit of 120 seconds regarding response times. Which results in a

```
"500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection"
```

response whenever the application does not finish file processing within those 120 seconds.

Is there a way to notify Gorouter that a connection is still valid, or some way to configure this when deploying application to Cloud Foundry (manifest.yml)?

I have this issue for multiple Java and Python applications.

Comment: Do the work outside a single request-response cycle. Return 202 Accepted with a Location header to poll for progress. See e.g. https://farazdagi.com/posts/2014-10-16-rest-long-running-jobs/

Comment: As @jonrsharpe said: Decouple the submission of the task and retrieving the result. Either by polling or by returning a task ID which could then be used to retrieve the result (maybe status: unknown, processing, done)

Comment: Thank you for the hints and the link. But how would this work, if multiple instances of this application are running? Since there is this load balancer in front, the background task would only exist on one instance. So if another app is polling if the result is ready, wouldn't it be a problem if the load balancer routes to the instance where the task is not being processed?

Comment: The initial request is going to return some sort of identifier for the task of work that needs to be completed. Regardless of where that task is actually executed, the entire system should be able to locate the identifier and report on its status. For example, I submit a PDF and get back id `x-42`. That id and the status of my job are stored in a DB. I can then query given the ID to get the status of the job cause it's coming from the DB. The DB is updated by the job as it progresses. When it's finished, accessing the id could link to the actual output.